# APC: apc_fetch returns false often, but sometimes success

Tags: php, caching, apc, litespeed

- APC Version : 3.1.9.
- PHP Version : 5.2.17
- i use Litespeed
- DEFAULT PHP: 5
- PHP4 SAPI: cgi
- PHP5 SAPI: dso
- SUEXEC: enabled

I create 2 file.
First file, set apc var :

```
<?php
$bar = 'BAR';
apc_store('foo_test', $bar);
echo 'stored';
?>
```

Second file, try to get apc var :

```
<?php
var_dump(apc_fetch('foo_test'));
?>
```

I visited first file, everything is fine.
I open second file, i refresh several times, usually (almost 90%), it returns false. And rarely returns correct response.

Here is my APC setting.

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  1
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   20M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    512M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    0
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: If you try to manually set ttl does it behave same way? `apc_store('foo', $bar, 1800);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Litespeed is running PHP with FastCGI. So it's spawning some child processes and then dispatch the requests between them. The problem is that *probably* APC stores the data in the heap memory (not in the shared memory), so every FastCGI instance has it's own APC data. The data in one instance will not be visible in the other instances. You set the data in instance #1, but then your fetch request goes to instance #2, instance #3... and you get FALSE. When you hit the instance #1, then you'll receive the saved value.

Edit: Compiling the APC module with `--disable-apc-mmap` (Disable mmap support and use IPC shm instead) should fix the issue.

Comment: @strkol you are correct, APC does not share its cache between child processes - that is something where using memcache would be a better option.

Comment: After i check, i use SuPHP, not FastCGI. Should i use `--disable-apc-mmap` too?

Comment: However my hosting said he is unable to enable fastcgi on litespeed. what if i still use suphp? or if i switch to dso?

Comment: It should work fine (without recompiling APC), if you switch to DSO

Comment: I have switched to DSO, but the scripts above are still failed.. Any idea?

Comment: How many Litespeed processes do you have? I'm afraid that if you have more than 1 process, you'll have the same problem as with fastcgi/suphp, so you should try to recompile APC with --disable-apc-mmap